# Расширения для Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, extension

Интересует след.вопрос. На каком ЯП и с использованием каких API я могу написать расширения для браузера (в данном случае Chrome), чтобы можно было использовать в расширении работу с файловой системой Windows?

Интересует работа с WORD, PDF внутри браузера. Обычный JS такого сделать не сможет. Вот и решил посмотреть в сторону расширений. Возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index
Открытие документов doc(x) или pdf средствами JS возможно. Либы легко гуглятся или легко ищутся на github.

Comment: Хорошо, Спасибо!!

Тоесть получается можно реализовать подобное и без расширения? А на прямую через JS

Comment: Открыть для чтения - да. Такие либы есть. Встречал редактор word на js

Comment: Хорошо. а переконвертирование тоже?

Comment: Ну в pdf средствами браузера по умолчанию. Просто печать с сохранением в pdf. А вот из pgf в word - это навряд ли, но не уверен. Ни чего не стоит на месте. Может кто-то уже заморачивался над этим.

Comment: Хорошо, понял, спасибо!